# send additional parameters to breeze-saving-server functions

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, breeze, durandal-2.0

I work in durandal project.
I use breeze to retrieve and save my data.
I want to send to the server, on saving, additional parameters other than the entity, like- who is the user that save the entity.
but, function saveChanges of breeze accept only one parameter- entities array for saving.

what can I do?

Comment: Why dont you just update your model to include these fields? Or make each of your objects inherit from a base class that has these properties?

Comment: We've talked about adding a custom property that you can use to send any arbitrary serializable object. GO vote for that on user voice. Another alternative: a custom header.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the SaveOptions.tag property.  Something like this:

```
var so = new SaveOptions({ resourceName: "SaveWithComment", tag: "Whatever data you want" });
return myEntityManager.saveChanges(null, so);
```

The 'tag' property is made available on the server within the ContextProvider, so you can access it like this:

```
// within your server side ContextProvider
protected override bool BeforeSaveEntity(EntityInfo entityInfo) {
   var tag = (string)SaveOptions.Tag;
   ...

}
```

Comment: Thanks for that - this was useful for passing in additional API versioning info to the server without changing the interface